# Why is my solution of integration wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

[image]

I thought I could do what I did but when I looked at the answer its done differently. I understand how its done correctly now but I'm curious what I did wrong so that I don't repeat my mistake in the future. To anyone that answers me THANKS!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your work gets to the point of claiming

$$\int \Big( \color{blue}{\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)} \sin(x) \cos(x) \Big) \, dx = \int \sin(x) \cos(x) \, dx$$

This does not hold. My guess is you tried to apply the Pythagorean identity,

$$\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$$

on the terms in blue, but you forgot about the $\sin(x)\cos(x)$ that are attached to the $\sin^2(x)$.

Comment: I figured that would be the source of my error. Thanks for confirming.